# cauchy sequence integers

Tags: cauchy-sequences

let $\{p_n\}$ be a sequence of integers. prove that if $\{p_n\}$ is cauchy, then $\{p_n|n \in N\}$ is finite.
my proof: don't know what else do it need or is it right please help...

pf: $Given, \{p_n\}$ is sequence of integers which is cauchy.

By definition of cauchy sequences,

For every $\epsilon>0,$ there exists N $\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ $ and$ $ m,n \geq N$

$|p_m-p_n|<\epsilon$

For  $ \epsilon $= $\frac{1}{2}$$ ,$ we have$ $ $|p_m-p_n|$ $<\frac{1}{2} .$

Since $p_m$ and $p_n $are integers, $|p_m-p_n|=0$ $ or$ $ p_m=p_n$ for all $ m,n \geq N$ for some $N \in$ $\mathbb{N} .$

All the terms after this are the same as and equal $p_m=p_n=p_N.$

Therfore, the set $\{p_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\} $ is finite and it contains atmost N elements namely $\{p_1,p_2,...,p_N\}$

(atmost because there might exist $ i,j<N $such that$ p_i=p_j$ $ i.e.$ elemets are repeated.

Comment: Can you have any $\epsilon <1$ in a sequence of integers (assuming standard metric on Reals)?

Comment: hmmm..i dont know (on reals)

Comment: Exactly, if you want $\epsilon <1$ , then your conclusion follows. I am saying your argument is correct.